# Java 7 on Mac OS X 10.6.8

Tags: java, macos

I've tried everything but I cannot get java 7 on mac os x 10.6.8.
This one didn't work either:
[How to install java jdk 7 on Snow Leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13536667/how-to-install-java-jdk-7-on-snow-leopard/14024322#14024322)
The file in the Java folder is called 1.7 but it is in fact 1.6.

What's the best way to install Java 7 on my OS?

Comment: "Best way"? Probably [`homebrew`](http://brew.sh/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mac OS X and multiple Java versions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252591/mac-os-x-and-multiple-java-versions)

Comment: What I do usually is download the jdk and then set the path properly in the  environment path. And also remove any other old java installation.

Comment: @cricket_007 the problem is that there are no java 7 downloads on Oracle for my computer version

Comment: Really? I can clearly see a link for `jdk-7u80-macosx-x64.dmg`

Comment: @PritamBanerjee what exactly do you mean? I have installed java 7 using some programs, but I wasn't "allowed" to replace some java folders, the system said

Comment: @cricket_007 that's for 10.7.3, not for 10.6.8

Comment: @cricket_007 but the installer doesn't work then because my mac OS is too old

Comment: Login as the superuser and remove the files. Then install java and then you can look at the java version. But remember to set the path correctly in the environment path.

Comment: @PritamBanerjee what's the superuser? the admin?

Comment: @J_from_Holland Yes. It is the admin.

Comment: @PritamBanerjee but what will happen when it goes wrong? Won't I have java then on my comp?I've already backed up the folder somewhere else, but is that enough?

Comment: Ideally it should not get wrong. Did you try following the steps in this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755900/installing-jdk-7-on-mac-os-10-6-8?rq=1

Comment: @PritamBanerjee I got to this point: currently there is a 1.7.0 jdk in the Java Virtual Machines folder, but mac acts like there isn't one. It just says that my java version is 1.6.